# Hide labels when are covered from a polygon

Tags: label, qgis, atlas

I need to mask all labels from a layer when they are outside a covering vector. On the image below there are contours; the lines are visible only if they intersects a polygon from a mask layer that is excluded with a filter.
I'm be able to hide the lines that doesn't intersects the polygon, but I can't do the same with the labels.
[image]

I'm using QGIS 3.22, below the filter managed from atlas.

[image]

Comment: check out label masking - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354539/mask-labels-in-qgis-3-12

Answer (score 0):

You should to clip your polygon by mask before show the labels.

You can do that using this tools:

> clip vector by mask layer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGw8N.png)